# R: 3D scatter plot from multiple 3D arrays in scatterplot3d

Tags: r, 3d

I'm new to R so please bear with me; I have six 3D arrays (c0, ..., c5) and I need to overlap the individual arrays into one 3D scatter plot. I have one scatter plot using the c0 array with...

```
library(scatterplot3d) ; scatterplot3d(c0)
```

... and get the following plot:

[image: plot]

Any idea how to add on the other five arrays, with different colors & shapes?
Also, any other suggestion for interactive use? Like python's 3D plots allow for zooming, rotating plot for different views, etc.

UPDATE:
The c0 array is as follows (used read.table('...')); there are 1000 elements, but this will give an idea.

`> c0
         C4_1548     Mg2_2796     Si4_1393
1    0.703216519  0.611332440  0.715913967
4   -0.073868874  0.333571615  0.174178337
5    0.584873346 -0.398325128 -0.038525721`

Comment: can we please have a reproducible example? (You can make up an array with random numbers in it, if you like.)  See the `rgl` package for dynamic 3D graphs ...

Comment: I updated the original post as idk how to make it look nice in comments. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: good effort, but that's not a reproducible example ...  Something like `cList <- replicate(3,setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=3)),c("A","B","C")),simplify=FALSE); c0 <- cList[[1]]; c1 <- cList[[2]]; c2 <- cList[[3]]` ...